# How to hide a div between two sizes in CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, screen

I stuck to hide div between two screen size. like I want to hide div between screen sizes 550px - 910px with the following media query.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 550px) - (max-width: 900px)
{

  .bsp_big-image{
      display: none !important;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the following syntax to do it:

```
@media (min-width: 550px) and (max-width: 900px)
{

  .bsp_big-image{
      display: none !important;
  }

}
```